# How to separate admin files and folders from public files and folders with Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, content-management-system, zend-framework2

i'm new in **zend framework 2**

i want to write a simple cms using zend framework2, but in start i want to separate the admin modules(files and folders) from the public.

i was built a simple cms before with this strategy

```
 -public
        -admin
              index.php
              -other folders related to admin

        index.php
        about.php
        -other folder and files related to public view
```

can anyone give me a simple Cms building with Zend framework 2 or explain for me what to do?

sorry for my bad English
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by : "give me a simple Cms writing"?

Comment: built with zend framework 2

Answer (score 2):

A ZF2 module can already contain its own routes, controllers, views, and public resources (the latter via the zf2-assetic-module). A single ZF2 app with two self-developed modules - one for the front-end and one for the admin back-end - should satisfy your separation criteria.

Note that you would typically still use a single `public/index.php` with a single `.htaccess` routing all non-resource (img, css, js, etc) requests to that `index.php` file.

Sounds to me like a deeper understanding of how ZF2 works would address most of your questions.

Comment: thanks David, can you give me more detail about it, or offer me a book?

Comment: I'd say the best resources are the official [ZF2 User Guide](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#userguide) and this [Evan Coury talk about modules](http://evan.pro/zf2-modules-talk.html)

Comment: Actually, this [module post](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/modules-in-zf2/) from Rob Allen is probably more accessible for the beginner than Evan's talk.